# Calculate datetime difference in automapper mapping (UseValue)

Tags: c#, datetime, automapper

I have situation where I need to know difference between two dates in days. I wanna do this in `mapper conf`.

The problem is I dont know is this possible and how?

Here is example code:

```
CreateMap<Post, ManagePostViewModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.ActiveInDays, conf => conf.UseValue((DateTime.UtcNow - (conf.CreatedAt)).TotalDays));
```

I tested this syntax in static values and it works. If I use `conf.CreatedAt` it dosn't, gives following error:

> 'IMemberConfigurationExpression' does not contain definition for 'CreatedAt' and no extension method 'CreatedAt' accepting a first argument of type 'IMemberConfigurationExpression' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In `model` and `viewModel` i have defined `CreatedAt`.

Comment: You typed `conf.CreatedAt`. That's not your ViewModel, that's the `IMemberConfigurationExpression` object that allows you to create an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is a typo: you typed `conf.CreatedAt`. `conf` is not your ViewModel, that's the `IMemberConfigurationExpression` object that allows you to create mapping expression.

The second problem is that `UseValue` is used to calculate a value only once, hence it doesn't provide access to the ViewModel. You need to use `MapFrom` to calculate a value for each individual ViewModel.

The final problem is that Automapper isn't supposed to work like that. It should *map* one property to another, not generate new values. The best place to calculate a duration is the target ViewModel. This will make changing and testing the duration calculation code a *lot* easier.

In the current scenario, you should map `CreatedAt` to a similar property in your ViewModel and add a read-only property that returns `DateTime.UtcNow - CreatedAt).TotalDays`. Using C# 6 syntax this would be a simple

```
public double ActiveInDays => (DateTime.UtcNow - conf.CreatedAt).TotalDays;
```

Perhaps a better option would be to return the TimeStamp itself and specify a formatting string in your data binding

```
public double ActiveDuration => DateTime.UtcNow - conf.CreatedAt;
```

This will allow you to display date fractions as hours, minutes etc.

If you *have* to perform the calculation while mapping, you should try:

```
.ForMember(model => model.ActiveInDays, 
          conf => conf.MapFrom(
                 model => (DateTime.UtcNow - model.CreatedAt).TotalDays
          ))
```

I think it's obvious that using a read-only property is a lot cleaner.

**Update**

If the intent is to show full days, the [Days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx) property should be used instead of `TotalDays`.

Comment: I used used read-only property as You suggested and it's working. Thank You!

Comment: Yes, true about Using Days property. I don´t know why i didn´t use this in first place... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ResolveUsing method.  [Additional information](http://blog.travisgosselin.com/automapper-mapfrom-vs-resolveusing/)

```
    public MappingProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Post, ManagePostViewModel>().ForMember(d => d.ActiveInDays, conf => conf.ResolveUsing(CalculateActiveDays));
    }

    private static object CalculateActiveDays(Post arg)
    {
        return (DateTime.UtcNow - arg.CreatedAt).TotalDays;
    }
```